# numpy concatenate multiple arrays arrays

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

I have many numpy arrays of shape (Ni,227,227,3), where Ni of each array is different.

I want to join them and make array of shape (N1+N2+..+Nk,227,227,3) where k is the number of arrays.

I tried numpy.concatenate and numpy.append but they ask for same dimension in axis 0. I am also confused on what is axis 1 and axis 2 in my arrays.

Comment: `np.concatenate(alist, axis=0)` should work.  Don't do this in a loop - collect a list of all the array, and do one concatenate.  Forget about `np.append`.

Comment: What's alist here?

Comment: `alist` of all the arrays you want to join!

Comment: np.concatenate([a,b,c,d],axis=0) gives me ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimension, ----- and the shapes are (1500, 227, 227, 3) (1500, 227, 227, 3) (0,) (1380, 227, 227, 3)

Comment: The `(0,)` does not have the same number of dimensions as the others.

Comment: Oh, I see, that was the problem (Also 4th array has different dimension). It was an empty array so concatenate doesn't work with empty arrays?

Comment: 0-dimensional arrays can't be concatenated.  But a (0, 227, 227, 3) shape array could be concatenated with your other arrays, even though it is empty.  The `1380` in the 4th array isn't a problem since you are concatenating on the first (0-th) axis. Practice concatenating small arrays where you can see what's happening!

Comment: yes, I understood. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the main problem here was with the one of the arrays of shape (0,) instead of (0,227,227,3).

np.concatenate(alist,axis=0) works.